# Remove node from JSON and shift children up

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have some JSON and would like to remove a node from the JSON but move the nodes inside the removed node to its parent.

Here is the JSON I am starting with:

```
{
    "Response": {
        "Outcome": {
            "KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu": [
                {
                    "Key": "Icon",
                    "Value": {
                        "DataType": "System.String",
                        "Field": "Icon",
                        "Value": "O"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Key": "IconDescription",
                    "Value": {
                        "DataType": "System.String",
                        "Field": "IconDescription",
                        "Value": "Old"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Key": "IconLongDescription",
                    "Value": {
                        "DataType": "System.String",
                        "Field": "IconLongDescription",
                        "Value": "Older"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

This is JSON I want to end up with.  I need the `KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu` node removed, but its children must still be present in the JSON:

```
{
    "Response": {
        "Outcome": [
            {
                "Key": "Icon",
                "Value": {
                    "DataType": "System.String",
                    "Field": "Icon",
                    "Value": "O"
                }
            },
            {
                "Key": "IconDescription",
                "Value": {
                    "DataType": "System.String",
                    "Field": "IconDescription",
                    "Value": "Old"
                }
            },
            {
                "Key": "IconLongDescription",
                "Value": {
                    "DataType": "System.String",
                    "Field": "IconLongDescription",
                    "Value": "Older"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tried to remove the node like this, but that is as far as I got:

```
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(Convert.ToString(jsonText));

var x = rss.Remove("KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu");
```

How can I move the children up?

Comment: I think JObject  is a class with predefined properties. What you want to do is changing your class definition  in runtime, and it's impossible

Comment: @MazaherBazari [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) is really more like a `Dictionary` where key-value pairs (properties) can be added and removed at will.  It is built for manipulating JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`SelectToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) and [`Replace`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Replace.htm):

```
JObject rss = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
rss.SelectToken("Response.Outcome")
   .Replace(rss.SelectToken("Response.Outcome.KeyValueOfstringOutcomepQnxSKQu"));
jsonText = rss.ToString();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/L6XoAf